# Generate opening book and endgame database for abstract strategy game

Tags: database-design, data-structures, artificial-intelligence

From test-playing my abstract strategy game vs the AI, I noticed that the first few moves and the endgame moves take more time than the mid-game.

What is a good method to generate an opening book and endgame database and what should be stored in these db's?

Maybe one can use the perft function:

```
private long perft(IBoard boardCopy, int depth)
{
    long nodes = 0;

    List<Move> moves = boardCopy.getMoves();

    if (depth == 1) return moves.size();

    for (int i = 0, n = moves.size(); i < n; i++) 
    {
        boardCopy.make(moves.get(i), true);
        nodes += perft(boardCopy, depth - 1);
        boardCopy.undo(moves.get(i));
    }

    return nodes;
}
```

And it can be enhanced to save a copy of the current position and the score?

Should this information then be fed to the move generation function or to the search itself?

Answer (score 1):

For opening, you need to have a way to precalculate moves. Then you store a hash of the game state and the move to make. Google Zobrist Hashing.

For endgames, depending on the game, you could start from positions that ends the game. Google Endgame Tablebases. They are built by Dynamic Programming from winning positions, by playing the game "backwards". Any position that can force a winning position is marked as a winning position etc. Store the hashes of winning positions, the distance in moves to win, and possibly the best play.